# Share android project between osx and windows

Tags: android, windows, macos

Im using an macbook pro in school and my win stationary at home.
In other programming i have usually just used dropbox as save place,and made sure to sync before opening.

Tried the same with eclipse on android programming but got a real hassle with errors all over. Now i have moved over to Android studio, can anyone suggest how to best handle this?

I mean theres got to be a correct project sharing way?
what do bigger companies do on large projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [git](http://git-scm.com/) for that.

create your repository on [github](http://www.github.com) or [bibucket](http://www.bitbucket.org) or your own server and easily share your work.

Comment: @Mohammad-Rahchamani What about machine dependent properties, like SDK location,...

Comment: @AVEbrahimi you should use .gitignore file for machine dependent properties files, and in android, you can use eclipse built-in git compatibility to share your project without problem.